# CSS Progress bar is out of place, how to keep it in place?

Tags: html, css

I have four progress bars. They are supposed to stay within the grey area container. It is instead going under the footer, as shown in images screen shots below.

The code of the bars was made so that I can position them around, and it's not just stuck to one area.

That is the [code to the progress bars](http://cssdesk.com/PNftj):

HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 90%"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 70%"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 50%"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 90%"></span>

        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 90px;
}

.meter {
    height: 15px;
    /* Can be anything */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #555;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 210px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.meter > span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43, 194, 83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84, 240, 84)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 67%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.  You are however putting your wrapper positioned relative to the empty section.container.  The section.container has no width and height set so you get the element not going where you think it should.

Simply give your container a `min-height` of your choosing, and you can move it within it's boundaries.

```
 <section class="container" style="min-height: 300px;">
   <section class="wrapper">
     <div class="meter"> <span style="width: 90%"></span>
     </div>
      ...
   </section>
 </section>
```

I would also put your page's content into your section.container (the p tags in this case).  Then you can move the bars anywhere on your page.

`position: absolute` lets you specify coordinates (top, bottom, left right) to move around in something `position: relative`.  If that relative thing has no width (or less width than the element you're positioning, then you're bound to get footers under things and such.

Answer (score 0):

Add these new CSS and see?

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:100px;
    padding:
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#footer{
    position:absolute;    
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Yikes,  but looks what happened, I tried your code (removed the grey background you added): http://i.imgur.com/jyGGKG6.png  Idk 8?

Comment: oops, you are using a lots of position for your site, if you use float, you can easily manage as you wish, let me see the workaround first.

Comment: oh yeah, it was custom made for me by someone else. The issue with changing othe CSS properties of the page is it will mess up my homepage or other pages. The homepage is really complex lol. But okay sounds good, hopefully there is some way,

Comment: or you can setup your demo for who want to test.

Comment: Here's what happened: http://i.imgur.com/LOSMVOl.png   (also the footer property messes up the footer on all the other pages) Sorry, I dont know, maybe its not possible? I never wouldof imagined it was going to be this hard, gerrr.